# ASP.NET Retrieving form values for the same database field Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a Form which will dynamically add textboxes for a particular database field. I wanted to use Model Binding to retrieve values from the Form on a Controller. I know Model Binding uses the textbox's id to retrieve values. However it's never recommended to have multiple textboxes with same ID as its unique. I have it such that in case a user needs more textboxes for the same field, they can add them dynamically by clicking a button. How do I retrieve values from these textboxes? Is there a way I can use html classes with model binding to retrieve the values instead? Or should I do it like this

```
       public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
        {
   // ModelBinder will set "form" appropriately
      foreach(var value in form.Getvalues("duplicatedFieldId"))
         {
          //do something with value
         }
        }
```

Regards

Comment: Model binding does not use a controls `id` attribute, it uses a controls `name` attribute. What is the model you want to bind to (a simple array of `string` or a collection of complex objects)?

Comment: I want to pass an array of string items retrieved from the textboxes. Can I give the textboxes the same name then iterate through them and retrieve there values?

Comment: Give each textbox the same name attribute (say `<input type="text" name="myName" />`) and then post to `public ActionResult MyAction(string[] myName) {` (or `List<string> myName`) then you can loop through the values. Note duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html but duplicate `name` attributes are fine.

Comment: If you have added the previous comment as an answer, then I would have marked it as an answer. If you do so I'll make it for an answer for users who will view this later on.

Comment: @Stephen so ideally this should work  

`     public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection form)
        {
  List<string> emailList = new List<string>();
        foreach(var value in form.GetValues("TeamLeader"))
         {
          emailList.Add(value)
         }
        }`

Comment: You don't need (and should not use) `FormCollection` If the textboxes are named `TeamLeader` then the method should be `public ActionResult MyAction(List<string> TeamLeader)` - the collection will be bound when you post back

Comment: Model Binding will automatically map values Textboxes named TeamLeader into the List parameter passed. And in the case of my Form, I have multiple textboxes I need there values retrieved so the HTTPPOST action method will automatically look like this? **public ActionResult MyAction(List<string> TeamLeader, List<string> Implementer, List<string> Approver)**  Thanks a lot for engaging me so much

Comment: That why I asked if t was a collection of string or a collection of complex objects (which is obviously is even thought you said it was just an array of strings). This is not the way to do it for complex objects. I suggest you read my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options as to how to do this correctly

Comment: What do you mean by complex objects, because as I see it I have only passed 3 List<string> objects into the constructor. In this case will they be complex objects. Thanks for the links, am going through the answers there too.